# Deleted Ubuntu, can't boot anything

Tags: dual-boot, windows

The Ubuntu (14.04) partition was deleted, and now I can't boot Windows. (It was dual booting 8.1)

I've tried everything. I can't boot through CD, or the HDD hard drive. I've reset the BIOS settings, set CD-ROM too boot first, and the HDD to boot second. I don't have the windows install disk, but I do have the Ubuntu CD. but when attempting to boot to CD, I am either stuck with a "Boot from CD/DVD:" message, without being prompted to press a button, or I am given a grub error message "error: no such partition." then it gives me the grub rescue mode prompt. I've read about a dozen forum threads, and none have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite the MBR (Master Boot Record) of the hard drive using a Windows Recovery Disk. If you don't have one, you can legally download and burn one for yourself. You could e.g. follow the guide [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-recovery-disk). Then boot from it and select `Repair your Computer`, then `Troubleshoot`, launch a command prompt and enter

> bootrec.exe /ScanOS

Your Windows installation should be detected. To fix the boot problems run

> bootrec.exe /FixMBR

and

> bootrec.exe /FixBoot

and

> bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd

Then just reboot your PC and you should see your Windows again :)

Comment: I followed the steps you gave me, but instead of downloading and preparing an install CD, I was able to find the original Windows install disk.

Comment: Great, even better! So did it work?

Comment: I followed the steps you gave me, however instead of preparing a repair CD, I was able to locate the original install CD. After rebooting the computer, I was greeted with a Windows error saying my MBR was missing or corrupted. This is a Windows error, not a bios or grub error

Comment: I apologize for the first comment, hit enter and didn't see edit.

Comment: The method above should have actually fixed that problem. Did any of the commands return an error?

Comment: No, they all appeared to be successful. Should I try to do it again, just in case?

Comment: Would be an idea ;)

Comment: Tried to do what you said again, still no luck.

Comment: http://imgur.com/e3B5KIm
http://imgur.com/0xDzo1d

Comment: One last thing to try: since it says something about BCD, try `bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd` (Source: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392))

Comment: No problem :) Could you please mark my answer as the solution then? Thank you :)